# Reading char and int from text file - C

Tags: c

I have a text file containing 20 lines of text (number and name). I want to read these from the text file and then use them as parameters in a function.

My text file contains some 20 lines like this one below:

```
719 Chris
```

I have the following code but it doesn't work, and gives an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)`

```
void read() {
    int number;
    char name;
    char buffer[200];
    FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        printf("%d %s\n", &number, name);
        add(name, number)
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Was `printf` a typo of `sscanf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking whether the file was opened successfully. If `fopen` returns `NULL` and that value is stored in `fp`, then the function call `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (i.e. your program may crash).

Also, the line

```
printf("%d %s\n", &number, name);
```

will invoke undefined behavior, for two reasons:

1. The `%d` conversion format specifier requires that you pass an argument of type `int`, but you are instead passing an argument of type `int*`.
2. The `%s` conversion format specifier requires that you pass an argument of type `char *`, but you are instead passing an argument of type `char`.

Passing `name` also does not make sense, because it has never been assigned a value. You probably want to do something with `buffer` instead, as that contains the line that you just read using `fgets`.

My guess is that you want to use the function [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead of `printf`, like this:

```
sscanf( buffer, "%d %s", &number, name);
```

However, in that case, you must change `name` to an array, so that it can store several characters, instead of only a single character.

Here is the full code, which fixes all issues mentioned above:

```
void read()
{
    int number;
    char name[200];
    char buffer[200];

    FILE *fp = fopen( "text.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( sscanf( buffer, "%d %s", &number, name ) != 2 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Parsing error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        add( name, number );
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Note that you will have to `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use the function `exit`.

Comment: Good answer, but you might add that `read` is not recommended as an identifier at global scope because it might cause problems at link time since the name `read` is already used for the POSIX system call used by standard streams to read bytes from the system handles.

Answer (score 0):

I see several points that seem odd to me:

1. What does the `add()` function do and why doesn't it have a semicolon at the end? (like `add(name, number);`)
2. You should add a `fclose(fp);` to close the stream.
3. In your `printf()` you use the flag `%s` to print a char, except that `%s` prints a string, replace by `%c`.
4. You try to print the address of number via `&number`, except that it is the `%p` flag and not the `%d` flag to do it.
5. `number` and `name` look empty (and uninitialized!) at least at the first pass in `printf()`.

Comment: The OP is obviously trying to parse the file. instead of `printf`, they should be using `sscanf`.